# To incorporate find dialog similar to ms acess in my java data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a data table in my application built using JSF and primefaces 3.5 which populates the data from database.Since it is a large data set i have implemented **live scrolling** to fetch rows as and when end of scrolling is reached.In this data table i have incorporated the search functionality for each column of the table as shown in the showcase [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml).I am developing an application as part of re-platforming of one of MS access application to java web application.The customer has now changed the requirement where instead of the **find** text box for each column they want the find dialog similar to the one used in MS access as shown in the image below.

[image]

The dialog should contain all matching criteria as shown in the image.

Can someone please suggest how to incorporate the above feature by any means.It can be either using JSF or any other front-end technologies.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BalusC,I am using primefaces 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two options for this with the primefaces datatable:

- You could use a lazy table, providing the required filtering when executing the lazy statements.
- You could setup a custom filter that adapts to the constraints selected in the dialog.

The first approach would be preferable for huge amounts of data, because your live-scroll would just load entries that are *matching* the filter defined on the LazyModel.

The second approach would be faster to implement, but suitable for regular dataset-sizes I'd say.

---

#### Lazy Approach

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

You would need to implement your own `LazyDataModel` and handle the conditions in the `load()` Method. The concrete implementation of this completly depends on whether you are using sql-queries, or some sort of Entitymanager to load the data required. The load method just needs to take care to take the *filters* into account along with the required pageSize determined by your live-scrolling logic.

#### custom filter

This way would allow you to keep your current "logic" of fetching entities and completly work "on top" of the data.

looking at the example you already linked http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml (last column) you could solve this using some javascript along with the proper custom filter:

- setup the same custom filter for *all* columns of your table.
- hide the primefaes searchfields using some `css` (you are using them, customer just does not see them)
- Whenever the filter conditions on your dialog are changing, set the corresponding filter-input to a value (based on your conventions) and call `PF('table').filter()` afterwards.

i.e. "Look In":

- "Current Field": Update only the respective (hidden) input element. (Set others to `null` or `empty string`)
- "All Fields": Update the global (hidden) input element.

i.e. "Match":

- WholeField: set a regular String : `kitchen` to the fields of the required "Look In".
- StartOfField: use some Wildcard-Identifier behind: `kitchen%`.
- EndOfField: use some Wildcard-Identifier behind: `%kitchen`.
- AnyPartOfField: use Wildcards on both sites: `%kitchen%`.

ps.: Use some Asci-Character no body would search like ❤ :P

After calling `PF('table').filter()`, your custom filter will be invoked, which could look roughly like this:

```
public boolean filterColumn(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
   String filterText = (filter == null) ? null : filter.toString().trim();

   //no filter?
   if(filterText == null||filterText.equals("")) {
        return true;
   }

   //cell empty?
   if(value == null) {
        return false;
   }

   String valueText = (String)value; //assuming only strings

   //"contains"
   if (filterText.startsWith("%") && filterText.endsWith("%")){
      return valueText.contains(filterText);
   }

   //"endsWith" - Yes wildcard at the BEGINNING is a endsWith!       
   if (filterText.startsWith("%")){
       return valueText.endsWith(filterText);
   }

   //"startsWith"
   if (filterText.endsWith("%")){
        return valueText.startsWith(filterText);
   }

   //no wildcards? "exact match"!
   return  valueText.equals(filterText); 
}
```

Aww, just saw you are on `3.5` - I think the custom Filter is available in `5.0+` only. But maybe it gives you a hint, or you can update PF.